# HTML button opening link in new tab

Tags: javascript, html

So this is the simple code for the button to open a certain link

```html
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="location.href='http://google.com';">
  Google
</button>
```

but it opens it on the same page, I want the link to open on a new tab though.

Comment: use `target="_blank"` to open in new page.

Answer (score 159):

You can use the following.

```
window.open(
  'https://google.com',
  '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
);
```

**in HTML**

```
 <button class="btn btn-success" onclick=" window.open('http://google.com','_blank')"> Google</button>
```

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/AGZLK6QscZ9chD9xKSAZ)

Comment: You should be using `<a>` instead of `<button>`. You can always style a `<a>` to look identical to a `<button>` (e.g. `appearance:`). Right now your HTML won't work for users with JavaScript disabled, or users that want to middle-click it either.

Answer (score 45):

With Bootstrap you can use an anchor like a button.

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

And use `target="_blank"` to open the link in a new tab.

Comment: nice..use padding:0.35em; and you get the look and feel...cool

Comment: Although I hit a problem that i needed to disable the button in some circumstances , and found cannot just use disabled attribute when using an anchor tag like I can for an actual button

Answer (score 17):

You can also add this to your form:

```
<form action="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
```

Answer (score 7):

Try using below code:

```
<button title="button title" class="action primary tocart" onclick=" window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank'); return false;">Google</button>
```

Here, the **`window.open`** with **`_blank`** as **second argument** of **`window.open`** function will open the link in new tab.

And by the use of **`return false`** we can remove/cancel the default behavior of the button like submit.

For more detail and live example, [**click here**](https://jsfiddle.net/enzuhox4/)

Answer (score 6):

To open a new tab with a button you just have to choose any of these options:

- Open link in a new tab hmtl:

```html
<a href="https://insert.url" target="_blank">The Website Linked</a>
```

- Button open link in new tab:

```html
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick=" window.open('http://google.com','_blank')"> Google</button>
```

- Open new tab when clicking link html:

```html
<!-- add target="_blank" to open new tab when link is clicked [in HTML]-->
<a href="YourLink" target="_blank">YourText</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use '_blank'. It will not only open the link in a new tab but the state of the original webpage will also remain unaffected.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.

```
<input type="button" value="Open Window"
onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com')">
```

Answer (score 1):

For React event listeners

```js
onClick={() => {window.open('https://www.google.com/');}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're in pug:

```
html
    head
        title Pug
    body
        a(href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank") Example
        button(onclick="window.open('http://www.example.com')") Example
```

And if you're puggin' Semantic UI:

```
html
    head
        title Pug
        link(rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.3.3/dist/semantic.min.css')
    body
        .ui.center.aligned.container
            a(href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank") Example
        .ui.center.aligned.container
           .ui.large.grey.button(onclick="window.open('http://www.example.com')") Example
```

Answer (score 0):

In end of the form button can be added like this using  ***target="_blank"***

```
<a href= {{$example->hosted_example_url }} class="button" target="_blank">View</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**For button issue solved you can follow my way:**

To open page in same tab use this code

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" onclick="window.location.href='www.mysite.com';">Reservation</button>
```

To open page in a new tab use this code

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" onclick="parent.open('www.mysite.com')">Reservation</button>
```

Here do the change only with [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
window.open(urlValue, "_system", "location=yes");
```

Answer (score -1):

use:

```
window.open('https://www.google.com');
```

in your js file

Comment: Please improve your answer by explaining it