# Buttons on html page won't open up to separate page

Tags: html, css, web, button

I am having trouble getting the buttons at the bottom of my home page to link to my other pages that contain various information, like tables I made in access. This is the final project for an  intro college class about information technologies and I've never made a website.

Tried a lot of different things, but it only seems to work on a computer where all the files are already downloaded, and not from a non local server.

You should be able to click on the  buttons at the bottom and it will open up a separate page that contains other information. All the other files im trying to upload into the code have been saved as .html

```
<html><head>
</head><body bgcolor="#808080" <link="" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


<h1>
    Serial Killers
</h1>
<h3>LIS 351 Final Project by Luke Tinsey</h3>
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/59/56/be/5956bef9b1d3384714d5e37826e41055.png" alt="Serial Killer Collage" width="400" height="300">
<p style="font-size: 25px;">
    My project is about serial killers and I'm interested in creating a database that includes details about some of the most infamous killers in the world.
    I list things such as their names, methods of killing, hometowns, confirmed and potential kills.
</p><p>
</p><p style="font-size: 25px;"></p>
    The serial killers I focused on are:
    <ul>
    <li>1. Ted Bundy</li>
    <li>2. Jeffrey Dahmer</li>
    <li>3. Harold Shipman</li>
    <li>4. Belle Gunness</li>
    <li>5. John Wayne Gacy</li>
    <li>6. Edmund Kemper</li>
    <li>7. Gary Ridgway</li>
</ul>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p>Click the links below for some more information!</p>
<button onclick="window.location.href='SerialKillersInfo%20Query.html'">Serial Killer Information</button>
<button onclick="window.location.href='Method%20Query.html'">Methods</button>
<button onclick="window.location.href='Documentation%20Query.html'">Documentation</button>
<button onclick="window.location.href='Method_Killer%20Query.html'">Cold Weather Correlation</button>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<button onclick="window.location.href='citations.html'">Citations</button>
<button onclick="window.location.href='Reflection%20Response.htm'">Reflection Response</button>
</body></html>
```

Comment: can you share some of the code?

Comment: sorry, just did

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML button opening link in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34082002/html-button-opening-link-in-new-tab)

Comment: This is from a file from access and word and another html page. I understand how to do buttons with url's but when I open the html pages and copy  those url's into my code it won't show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your other .html files are located in the same folder/directory as this file, then change your links to this.

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='./SerialKillersInfo%20Query.html'">Serial Killer Information</button>
```

I also highly suggest that you remove the spaces in the document names and insted have
SerialKillersInfoQuery.html

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='./SerialKillersInfoQuery.html'">Serial Killer Information</button>
```

in short just add ./infront of the names of your html files.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to add a link to a button would actually be to use an a tag.

Then, you can use a little bit of css to make your tag look like a button
Here is an example, you can simply replace what's in the href with your html file

```
<a href="file.html">Click Here!</a>
```