# How do I make a button act like a link but on a new tab?

Tags: html

I was using a button to go to a new link, but kept going on to the preview.

I tried using:

```html
<button type="button" onclick="window.location.href = 'www.typing.com' target = '_blank'">Typing.com</button>
```

I expected it to bring me to a new tab, but what happened is this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier (: line 112)

when I don't even have line 112.

Comment: Have a look on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34082002/html-button-opening-link-in-new-tab)

Comment: window.location.href = 'www.typing.com' target = '_blank' is not valid code. If you look at @AlexandreB. link you will see onclick=" window.open('www.typing.com' ,'_blank'); return false;" which is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line of code won't work because you're not quoting it properly:

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.location.href = 'https://www.typing.com' target = '_blank'">Typing.com</button>
```

For starters, this isn't valid JavaScript.

```
window.location.href = 'https://www.typing.com' target = '_blank'
```

You haven't defined a variable called `target` and you're supposed to put semi-colons after assignments.

I think you meant to write this instead:

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='https://www.typing.com'" target="_blank" id="myButton">typing.com</button>
```

Even if you change it to that, it won't work as expected because you can't use an [anchor tag's target attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) on a button and you can't set it using an assignment to `window.location.href`.

---

If you ***must*** use inline scripting, use the `window.open` function, then add a second argument (`"_blank"`), like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.open('https://www.typing.com', '_blank');" id="myButton">typing.com</button>
```

---

If you're trying to make a button behave like an anchor tag using inline scripting, why not use an actual link and style that like a button instead?

Set the anchor tag's `target` attribute to `_blank`, like this:

```
<a href="https://www.typing.com" target="_blank" class="button">Typing.com</a>
```

Here are some basic styles for a (blue) button:

```
.button {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #03A9F4;
}
```

---

If you want to go down the JavaScript route, ignore the first two methods and just add a click event to your button elements, like this:

```
document.querySelector(".button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  window.open("https://www.typing.com", "_blank")
});
```

Notes and information:

- the `_blank` argument is required for it to open in a new tab.
- you have to use a `for` (or `forEach`) loop to add the click event to each button.
- your *"link"* won't work if the user is has a popup blocker (extension) installed.

Good luck.

Comment: One thing, is ,   that in the window.open("www.typing.com", "_blank");

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code code snippet.

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.open('www.yoursite.com');"
 id="myButton">typing.com</button>
```