# Creating a dynamic number of buttons with a dynamic URL

Tags: javascript, button, tabs

I feel so close to this one. I just can't get the buttons generated to open up in a new tab. I'm stuck!

```
     function buildButton(url,i,size) {
            document.write("Building Button with URL= "+url+"<p>");

            var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
            btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("PIDs "+i+" to "+(i+size)));
            btn.setAttribute("href",url);
            btn.setAttribute("target","_blank");
            document.body.appendChild(btn);


}
```

Comment: Well, buttons don't really have the `href` attribute. Use an `a` (anchor) tag for links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change the `<button>` tag to `<a>` tag**

Buttons doesn't have the `href` and `target` attributes, the `<a>` tag has. The code should be like this:

```js
function buildButton(url,i,size) {
  document.write("Building Button with URL= "+url+"<p>");

  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.appendChild(document.createTextNode("PIDs "+i+" to "+(i+size)));
  a.setAttribute("href",url);
  a.setAttribute("target","_blank");
  document.body.appendChild(a);
}

buildButton('https://stackoverflow.com/', 1, 1);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with:

```
function buildButton(url,i,size) {
    var btn = document.createElement("INPUT");
    btn.setAttribute("type","button");
    btn.setAttribute("onclick", "window.open('"+url+"')");
    btn.setAttribute("value","PIDs "+i+" to "+(i+size));
    btn.setAttribute("target","_blank");
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
    document.write("<p>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution based on this [HTML button opening link in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34082002/html-button-opening-link-in-new-tab). Looks like you have figured it out anyway

```
function buildButton(url,i,size) {
    document.write("Building Button with URL= "+url+"<p>");

    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("PIDs "+i+" to "+(i+size)));
    btn.setAttribute("onclick","window.open('" +url+"', '_blank')");

    document.body.appendChild(btn);
}  
buildButton("http://www.google.com","Thing", 44) ;
```