# Button that links to mulitple websites

Tags: javascript, html, random

I'm trying to create a button that links to random websites like on 'The useless web'. I found this code on here and it's worked almost perfectly. I just need help making the sites open in a new tab, at the moment they change the current window. Any help will be greatly appreciated. THANKS

CURRENT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var urls = [
    "http://www.kittenwar.com/",
    'http://heeeeeeeey.com/',
    'http://cat-bounce.com/'
];

function goSomewhere() {
    var url = urls[Math.floor(Math.random()*urls.length)];
    window.location = url; // redirect
}
```

onClick handler assigned:

```
<a href="#" onClick="goSomewhere(); return false;">Gimme something weird!</a>
```

Comment: already answered here, I believe - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window -- so as not to be evasive, you really can't do it this way, from javascript. You could put it on the page in an HTML form, have the form target be something new, and have javascript submit the form though!

Comment: Add target="_blank" to your link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34082002/html-button-opening-link-in-new-tab/46542656

Comment: @SethMcNaughton - there is no link, at least not yet! Otherwise, I think you have the right idea. At least in this example it's all js.

Answer (score 0):

use this function

```
 function goSomewhere() {
        var url = urls[Math.floor(Math.random()*urls.length)];
        window.open(url, '_blank')
    }
```

Comment: I don't suppose you can help me with one more thing (sorry I know I'm being cheeky). I'd like to add another button with the same functionality to a different page but I can't work out how...

Comment: just create one more function  and assing click to it.  https://jsfiddle.net/poyt7kfe/

Comment: So great! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

To open a page in a new tab, you should create the button like this:

```html
<button href='w3schools.com' target='_blank'>Click me!</button>
```

You can change the `href` tag with JavaScript.