# Pass and run JavaScript code in new window by clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, html

How do I make a html button run code?

What I'm trying to do is put a button `<button>` open a new page in `about:blank` and have the code that was in a `<textbox>` there.

I don't know how to make the `about:blank` page have the code though. I have tried:

```html
<button src="about:blank" target"_blank" data-uri="(I don't know what to put here or if this is even correct)">Click to run code</button>
```

I'm trying to implement it with HTML and JS. If anyone could help, that would be awesome!

Comment: What else do  need to add? plz don't make it -2 :(

Comment: I literally have no reputation oof

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML button opening link in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34082002/html-button-opening-link-in-new-tab)

Comment: @zinovyew no that tells me how to make it open a page, but now how to add code to about:blank or get text from a textbox and open it as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in almost all of the browsers (tested in both FF and Chrome):

```html
<!-- Your link !-->
<a id="externalLink" href="#/">Click to run the code</a>

<script>
  const el = document.getElementById('externalLink');

  // Create a content for a new page with a script in it
  const newPageContent = `
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>alert('Hello World!')<\/script>
    Hello world! 
  </body>
  </html>
  `;

  // Listen on "click" event
  el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Create a new window on click
    const w = window.open('', '_blank');

    // Write your content to it
    w.document.write(newPageContent);
  });
</script>
```

While I wasn't able to make the `href="data:text/html"` work properly. I assume that it should be forbidden by some security rules of the browser.